# File name with double quotes in S3 URL leads to Invalid Argument

Tags: php, mysql, xml, amazon-s3

When retrieving a URL string using AWS php sdk, I get an XML error if the file name has a double quote in it. The actual file name stored in S3 does not contain the double quote. But the end users wanted to be able to download the file (in this case a PDF) with a user friendly name.

In this case, the file name is:

```
3" PVC Lines
```

Notice that the double quote is used as a length indicator (inches, US). So replacing the double quote with anything will not produce a user friendly name.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$s3CMD = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
'Bucket' => $bucketName,
'Key'    => $actualBucketFileName,
'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'filename="' . $systemFileName . '"'
]);

$s3Request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($s3CMD, '+20 minutes');
$fileUploadNameURL = (string) $s3Request->getUri();
```

The file name stored in MySQL (designated by '$systemFileName' above) is:

```
3" PVC Lines.pdf
```

In the S3 bucket, it's something like

```
47258252485.pdf
```

The XML error I get is:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Header value contained an open quoted span.</Message>
    <ArgumentName>response-content-disposition</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>
        filename="3" PVC Lines.pdf"
    </ArgumentValue>
```

Attempting to add a slash in front of the double quote produces this file name:

```
3- PVC Lines.pdf
```

which isn't helpful to the end user.

So the question is, how do I allow the double quotes to be used as the file name in the argument ResponseContentDisposition?

Thanks

Comment: Putting a `"` in a filename seems like a bad idea anyway, but if you start in RFC-2183 and work backwards, it looks like the correct solution would be to escape it with a backslash ... `filename="3\" PVC Lines.pdf"`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - You're right that adding a double quote wasn't a good idea. In fact, Windows won't allow me to add it directly when trying to rename it in the explorer. But adding two single quotes has worked. As to your solution of `filename="3\" PVC`, this adds a dash when downloading the file, which doesn't help in this scenario.

Comment: Presumably the dash is happening because my suggestion actually works -- and then the quote mark is removed by the browser, since it isn't valid in a filename.  Your double single quote hack is visually convincing but definitely wrong and could cause problems for your users... using the word "inch" or an abbreviation -- `3-inch PVC` or `3-in PVC` would probably be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and errors, I decided to use str_replace to turn the double quotes to two single quotes. So this:

```
3" PVC
```

turned into this:

```
3'' PVC
```

only when using the S3 API to download the file with a proper file name. On here, the two single quotes look spaced out. But when you download a file, it looks just like a double quote, so the end user thinks it's still an inch representation.

This may seem like a very specific case, but it may help someone else who is trying to use the S3 API with double quotes in the file name.

My solution (unless someone replies with a better answer):

```
$badChars  = array('&ndash;','&rdquo;','&ldquo;','"','&quot;');
$goodChars = array('-','\'\'','\'\'','\'\'','\'\'');

$data      = trim(str_replace($badChars,$goodChars, $data));
```

Edit: None of the above solution replacements are being inserted into a database, just in case someone thought there may be some injection issue (using PDO, of course, anyway). The file name was safely inserted into MySQL. The original issue was about displaying it.